# ModuleNotFoundError - Python VSCode I can´t import modules:

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can´t import any module in VSCode.

The structure of my project is the next:
6.Python
-.vscode
-settings.json
-Ortiz
-**init**.py
-puntoentrada.py
-Paquetes
-Prueba1
-**init**.py
-prob.py

puntoentrada.py looks like this:
[puntoentrada.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJkIr.jpg)

Then, this is prob.py
I tried to run this but I have a problem called:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'puntoentrada'
[prob.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHzdR.jpg)

Then, this is the directory of Python
[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN15p.png)

Then, this is the variable environment
[PythonPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoL7s.png)

Then, this is my Python > Analysis Cache Folder Path in VSCode:
[Configure VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZJJP.png)
This is the same in "Usuario", "Area de trabajo" and "6.Python"

Then, this is my settings.json
[settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOBmh.png)

I only want to execute "prob.py" and the only task is "import puntoentrada", but I cant do it, because puntoentrada according to VSCode "does not exist"

So, what can I do?

Comment: According to the [mre] page, "`DO NOT use images of code`". Your example should only be the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VSCode, but a Python issue. Python looks in serveral places for packages and modules and you can inspect these places via the `sys.path`. If prob.py is your main script, Python finds all modules that are in the same folder as prob.py. If your script is in a subfolder, you have to tell that to Python:

`from subfolder import mymodule`

If the module is part of a package in a completely separate path, your best option is to install that package in editable mode:

`pip install path/to/mypackage -e`

But you have to have a `setup.py` in that second package.

A quick-and-dirty workaround would be to simply add that separate path to `sys.path` using the `append` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my Python version for the operating environment in these places.

On the top right corner, you can choose the Python Version.
[image]

[image]

On the left bottom corner, you can choose the Python version.